# Display Time in PST

Tags: php, timezone

What is easiest way to display the current time in PST (West Coast) time using PHP?

Answer (score 21):

Well, the easiest might be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

Take a look at [supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) to find one suitable for your needs.

Comment: Doesn't this set the server time? That's not what they're asking.

Answer (score 13):

Let's try a solution that uses PHP's modern date handling.  This example requires PHP 5.2 or better.

```
// Right now it's about four minutes before 1 PM, PST.
$pst = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$three_hours_ago = new DateTime('-3 hours', $pst); // first argument uses strtotime parsing
echo $three_hours_ago->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // "2010-06-15 09:56:36"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using or have access to Carbon you could do this:

```
$timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
$now = Carbon::now()->tz($timezone)->toDateTimeString();
echo $now;
```

Answer (score 0):

.

```
echo date('r');
putenv('TZ=PST');
echo date('r');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my projects without setting timezone. Google API daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). So I wrote this function to check time.

```
function date_pt($_format){
    $pacificTime = new DateTime();
    $pacificTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('PST'));
    return $pacificTime->format($_format);
}


echo date_pt("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //datetime Pasific Time
echo "<br/>";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //datetime server timezone
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a date/time between timezones:

```
include ("Date.php");
$d = new Date("2010-06-21 10:59:27"); // initialize object
$d->setTZByID("GMT"); // set local time zone
$d->convertTZByID("PST"); // convert to foreign time zone
echo $d->format("%A, %d %B %Y %T"); // retrieve converted date/time
```